# How to trigger quartz scheduler everytime i run my springboot project?

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am trying to add quartz scheduler to my springboot application to run cron job every night at 12 am. Here is my configuration

```
@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean demoJob() {
    JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    jobDetailFactory.setJobClass(DemoJob.class);
    jobDetailFactory.setDurability(true);
    return jobDetailFactory;
}


@Bean
public CronTriggerFactoryBean demoTrigger(
        @Qualifier("demoJob") JobDetail jobDetail) {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    trigger.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    trigger.setCronExpression("0 0 0 * * ?");
    trigger.setMisfireInstruction(CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING);
    return trigger;
}

@Bean
public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
    AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return jobFactory;
}
```

Now I need to trigger this job every time I run this project besides running it every night.
I tried setting

```
trigger.setStartTime(new Date());
trigger.setStartDelay(1);
```

But it does not trigger everytime I run this project. Can I set this configuration or have to use `@Postconstructor` at my method sign?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an event listener in your spring boot.
For your purpose you can stick to the `ApplicationReadyEvent` which is fired when, as the name suggests, the application is ready.

For example:

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    private final Scheduler scheduler;
    private final CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactory;
    private final JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationReadyEvent() {
        var fooTrigger = cronTriggerFactory.getObject();
        var fooJob = jobDetailFactory.getObject()
        scheduler.scheduleJob(fooJob, fooTrigger);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have this in my mind but at first, I want to be sure if I can do it by configuring the trigger.

Comment: Then try to use a `SimpleTriggerFactoryBean` - by default the start time is 'now' which should be the startup of the application. Further you can configure a start delay.